# Connected Marketing cloud connect and record got synced in 2 mins instead of 15 mins

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I connected marketing cloud connect and created and synced a lead record from salesforce to marketing cloud. I chose the poll schedule as 15 mins but I checked and after 2 minutes the record was synced to marketing cloud synchronized DE. How is that possible ?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? In that case, don't forget to [mark it as accepted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because the connector polls for new records every 15 minutes, not 15 minutes after the record is created. Let's say it polls 12:00, 12:15, 12:30 and 12:45. Your record is created 12:43. It will then be included in the 12:45 batch.